# Do moderators get to know about new questions coincidentally?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Almost every time I ask a question on SO, a few seconds( or at most a minute) later, someone with reps that reach the skies will surface and post a comment or an edit or something. This leaves me asking how they magically do that. Is there a system that alerts them or is it just a coincidence? Are they notified specially or like any other member?

Comment: This is probably just high-rep users who frequently refresh the list of new questions in the tags they follow.

Comment: They're probably just watching their tags for new questions. Stack Overflow uses websockets to pop-up and update a little banner when new quesitons are asked- The users just click on that and the list displays the new questions. That said, they may have other tricks I don't know about.

Comment: Also note: You use "moderators" in your title, but in reality I believe you just mean "high rep users" as there are only a handful of mods and I doubt they are managing to be that quick and active on all of your questions. (Mods have a diamond next to their name, like ChrisF below.)

Comment: @Kendra: Meh. Everyone is a moderator on the site. Most of us merely aren't *diamond* moderators.

Comment: @Kendra, you are right. As you can see my reps. I am really a beginner and so do not really know much of the inner workings of SO. Thanks for pointing that difference out.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I suppose that's true. Maybe I should stop arguing semantics and just roll with it.

Comment: Have you discovered looking at specific tags yet? That's the easiest way to see what's active and what's new in your area of expertise/interest. Say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java . Generally the "there are X new questions" banner pops up so often it is not a problem of finding questions, its a problem of picking one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no special system for notifying diamond moderators, high rep users or anyone else about new questions.

There are general notifications when new questions appear if you have the relevant page open. So the most likely explanation is that they have the home page (or their "interesting" tags page) open virtually all the time and spot when there are new questions.

They then click the link and read like everyone else.

The reason they have a high reputation score is that they participate in the site, answering questions etc., *a lot* so they know what to look for, what to fix and what to answer.

Comment: +1 for the understanding and patience with a low-rep member.